# Algebraic Multiplicity of Eigen Value of Matrix and Its Conjugate

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A∈M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a nonsingular matrix and $\bar{A}$ is conjugate of $A$, i.e. entries of $\bar{A}$ is obtained by replace entries of $A$ with their conjugate. Let $\lambda$ be the real negative eigenvalue of $A\bar{A}$. Prove the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ is even.

I've tried it if every entries of $A$ are real, the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ is $0$. But I can't generalize it if some entries of $A$ are not pure real or pure imaginary.

Comment: This question has been already asked  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135954/multiplicity-of-eigenvalues easlier.

Comment: Thank you, I coudn't find it before